# Question regarding the conditional probability of multiple events

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm having trouble really understanding a seemingly easy question about conditional probability. Here is the question:

Let $n_{R}$ denote the number of red balls in an urn and $N$ denote the number of balls (both red and blue).

a. Write the probability of the event for drawing two red balls out of three balls in terms of $n_{R}$ and $N$ when we do not replace each drawn ball. (Hint: There are three ways to select two red balls out of three drawn balls)

b. Write the probability of the event for drawing two red balls out of three balls in terms of $n_{R}$ and $N$ when we replace each drawn ball.

For a, I'm guessing I have to use a version of $P(R_1 \cap R_2) = P(R_2 | R_1)P(R_1)$ where $R_i$ denotes the event that the $i^{th}$ draw is a red ball.

But how would I put this in terms of $n_R$ and $N$? Honestly the only way I can think about doing it (from previous notes given by the professor) gives me this equation: $\frac{n_R}{N} \times \frac{n_R - 1}{N - 1} \times \frac{n_R - 2}{N - 2}$

Is there any easy way to understand this, or any good videos / books / tutorials that can help me understand this better? I'm pretty lost right now.

Comment: The notation is a little different from usual, but (a) is hypergeometric and (b) is binomial. These distributions are covered in almost all basic probability books, including possibly the one that contains this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(a) Hypergeometric.** An urn contains $N$ balls, of which $n_R$ are red.
We withdraw $d = 3$ balls without replacement. What is the
probability of getting $X = 2$ red balls. The general formula is
as follows:
$$P(X = x) = \frac{C(n_r, x)C(N-n_r,d-x)}{C(N,d)},$$
for $x = 0, \dots, d$, where the binomial coefficient
$C(a, b) = \frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}$, for integers $0 \le a \le b$, and $0$ otherwise.

The denominator $C(N, d)$ is the number of ways to select $d$ balls
from among $N$ with replacement, and without regard to order.
Similarly, the two factors in the numerator count the ways to select
$X$ red balls from among the $n_r$ red balls in the urn, and the
ways to select the remaining $d - x$ balls to be non-red, respectively.

Your attempt seems to keep track of order, but it does not seem to be
correct. Notice the hint about three ways to select 2 red balls out of
three draws. $P(2\: red\: in\: 3\: draws) = P(R_1R_2N_3) + P(R_1N_2R_3) + P(N_1R_2R_3),$ where the $N_i$ are non-reds.

*Example:* In case there are 5 balls in the urn of which 3 are red,
The the numerical probability of getting exactly 2 reds in 3 draws is
$\frac{3 \times 2}{10} = 0.6,$ computed from the hypergeometric formula.
Also, taking account of order and using your conditioning method,
the first of the three terms is $\frac{3}{5}\frac{2}{4}\frac{2}{3} = 0.2$
and the other two terms turn out to have this same probability for a total of 0.6.

**(b) Binomial.** If balls are replaced, then $X \sim Bin(d, n_r/N)$.
The general formula is:
$$ P(X = x) = C(d,x)(n_r/N)^x(1-n_r/N)^{d-x},$$
for $x = 0, \dots, d.$

Comment: Now that you know the right search words, 'hypergeometric' and 'binomial' you can do a Google search to find illustrations at your level. The Wikipedia articles have a few examples amongst the theory.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I'll check out some wikipedia articles